# Show that $\big(1+cis(x)\big)^n = (2^n)(\cos\frac{x}{2})^n(\cos \frac{nx}{2}+i\sin \frac{nx}{2})).$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Show that $\big(1+cis(x)\big)^n = (2^n)(\cos\frac{x}{2})^n(\cos \frac{nx}{2}+i\sin \frac{nx}{2})).$

Easy enough with $(cis)^n$ but not sure what to do with $(1+ ``{}")^n$

Comment: use $1+cos(X)=2cos^2(X/2)$ , $sin(X)=2sin(X/2)cos(X/2)$ and factor.

Comment: $1+e^{ix} = 2e^{ix/2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(1+\cos x+i\sin x)^n=\\(2 \times\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}+i \times2\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{2})^n\\=(2\times \cos\frac{x}{2})^n\times( \cos \frac{x}{2}+i \times\sin \frac{x}{2} )^n=\\
 (2\times \cos\frac{x}{2})^n\times(e^{i\frac{x}{2}})^n=\\
(2\times \cos\frac{x}{2})^n\times e^{i\frac{nx}{2}}=\\
$$